# Tap preview thumbnail to view high resolution image

Tags: android, menu, zooming, imagebutton

I am a new android developer and I am trying to create an android app for android in which menu items will be displayed along with description cost and image.
I have implemented List activity to display the items in a list. I made an image Button which will show the image in a thumbnail. I want to be able to view a high resolution image of the thumbnail  when I tap on the image button. I have implemented an onClickListener to listen to the tap event but I do not know the methods that will make the image zoom out on tap.

I have followed [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)

but it is quite ambiguous to understand. The Animator class doesn't exist. Can someone guide me out o fthis?

Comment: The Animator class does exist it was added in API 11. What API are you targeting?

Comment: my api version is 8. I think this is the reason why animator doesn't work. Is there ne other method to do the same job?

Comment: There are actually a whole bunch of ways to animate in Android. I'd look around for other animation tutorials, or you can use Jake Wharton's backport library NineOldAndroids http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: I have to embed the code to zoom in and zoom out multiple pages. I have almost 8 pages. with minimum three items on each. I want to write the code for the thumbnail of each item. If you could find me something simple it will be great. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
I found the solution after searching for almost a week.
I used PopupWindow Class for the purpose
Following is the Java Code.

PopupWin.java
public class PopupWin extends Activity{

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            final Button bPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
            bPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
         = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                 final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                   popupView, 
                   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);  

                 Button bDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                 bDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          popupWindow.dismiss();
         }});

                 popupWindow.showAsDropDown(bPopup, 50, -30);

       }});
        }
    }


popup.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dim_back" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dim_back"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/appetimg01" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:text="Go Back"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appetizerDes1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:text="Tap the Image to view High Resolution Image."/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/openpopup"
            android:layout_width="80sp"
            android:layout_height="80sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="40sp"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

The background was appearing white but I wanted it transparent for which I created back_dim.xml in drawables and set it along with android:background="@drawable/back_dim".
```